# javascript copy a variable for use in function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I'm not really sure how to word this question better, but basically my problem is this:

I have code like this (not exactly, this code is really simple and mine is a little more complicated):

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs[i] = function() { return i; };
}
```

So the idea is that each function in `funcs` will return each number from 0 to 9 when called. But the problem is that each one is still referring to the variable `i` when called, so they will all return 9. How do I get this work as intended (i.e. for all n, `funcs[n]() === n`)? How do I get each function scope to capture only the current value of `i`, not the value that changes?

Comment: how about declaring a local variable whose value is `i` within that function and return it instead?.

Comment: Obviously this is simplified code but if your functions differ only by the value of i it seems the "i" should really just be an argument.

Comment: call a function, creating a separate activation frame for each iteration

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I believe this should answer your question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). If it doesn't, please let me know.

Comment: Yes thank you that does answer it. I wasn't really sure what to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i could do like so :

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        funcs[i] = function () {
            return i;
        };
    })(i);
}
alert(funcs[3]());
```

creating a separate activation frame for each iteration

you can alternatively use map:

```
var numbers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
}

var funcs = numbers.map(function (i) {
    return function () { return i; };
});
alert(funcs[3]());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var funcs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    funcs[i] = makeFunction(i);
}

function makeFunction(i) {
    return function() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

`i` in the returned function is bound to the local variable `i` in `makeFunction` rather than `i` in your main block of code.